# How to pass validation_data in Model.fit method of keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am receiving following exception while calling `model.fit` method.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-a7c25bd01b61> in <module>()
      8            cv_x.school_state.values,cv_x.teacher_prefix.values,cv_x.project_grade_category.values,
      9            cv_x.clean_categories.values,cv_x.clean_subcategories.values],
---> 10            cv_y))

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    100                 'Expected to see ' + str(len(names)) + ' array(s), '
    101                 'but instead got the following list of ' +
--> 102                 str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
    103         elif len(names) > 1:
    104             raise ValueError(

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 8 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[  48,   24,    2, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [  40,  787,  310, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [   4,    5, 1474, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       ...,
       [1725, 2095,  716, ...,    0, ...
```

```
model = Model(inputs=input_a, outputs=[output])
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit([padded_docs_train,train_x.price,train_x.teacher_number_of_previously_posted_projects,
           train_x.school_state,train_x.teacher_prefix,train_x.project_grade_category,
           train_x.clean_categories,train_x.clean_subcategories], [train_y],epochs=12, batch_size=1000,
          callbacks = [print_auc,tensorboard],
          validation_data = ([padded_docs_cv,cv_x.price,cv_x.teacher_number_of_previously_posted_projects,
           cv_x.school_state,cv_x.teacher_prefix,cv_x.project_grade_category,
           cv_x.clean_categories,cv_x.clean_subcategories],[cv_y]))
```

If the same format is working for input parameters why it is giving exception for `validation_data`.
And how to pass parameters in `validation_data` properly.

The input layers in `input_a` are as follow:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'text_input:0' shape=(?, 500) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'price_input:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int64>,
 <tf.Tensor 'no_projects:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int64>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_school_state:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_teacher_prefix:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_project_grade_category:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_clean_categories:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'input_clean_subcategories:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int32>]
```

Comment: You are passing the data in a list whereas the keras's fit method expects the data to be in Numpy format. I would suggest updating the data to be in a numpy array both training and validation and it would work fine. All `train_x`, `train_y` and `test_x`, `test_y` should be of type numpy array.

Comment: I passed dictionary of input layer name as keys and numpy arrays of input and output as values for both train and validation data, but still getting the same excetion @IbtihajTahir

Comment: Can you tell me the value of `input_a`?

Comment: I have added values of input_a in the question. @IbtihajTahir

Comment: The error clearly mentions that it's expecting to see 8 arrays but instead it got only one array. Your `input_a` defines the number of arrays the model will expect and I can't seem to find it in your question.  You can also clearly see that you are providing a list of numpy array which has only shape 1 and it makes sense because the numpy array is the only object in the list hence the size of array is 1. Try giving the model directly the numpy array.